# Datatables - how to prevent sorted column from changing color

Tags: jquery, sorting, colors, datatables

Just started with Datatables. By default, when the user clicks a column row to sort, the whole column is shaded. Can somebody tell how to turn this feature off? I've been messing with the built-in CSS classes, and I had high hopes for the asSorting parameter, but I don't seem to be able to do it. If this is somewhere obvious on the Datatables web page and I'm not seeing it, sorry, but I can't find it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just remove styles for `td.sorting_1`.

Comment: This solution affects all tables. The solution proposed by seus (orderClasses option) is preferred as it uses the API instead of CSS manipulation.

Answer (score 51):

### v1.10+

As [Mathieu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1501801/mathieu) [indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441501/datatables-how-to-prevent-sorted-column-from-changing-color/22206115#comment49216565_22206115), [order classes](http://datatables.net/reference/option/orderClasses) can now be disabled by setting `orderClasses` to `false`.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "orderClasses": false
});
```

### v1.9-

As shown in: [DataTables:Features](http://datatables.net/usage/features), this functionality can be disabled by setting `bSortClasses` to `false`.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "bSortClasses": false
});
```

Comment: In the new features, the property has changed to "orderClasses".
http://datatables.net/reference/option/orderClasses

Comment: This is the best answer.